# Como posso descobrir, utilizando a linguagem C, qual ambiente gráfico está instalado no Linux?

Tags: c, linux, user-interface

Como posso descobrir qual ambiente gráfico está instalado? Exemplo:

KDE, GNOME, XFCE ou LXDE?

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a solução for muito simples ainda é possível que alguém o faça nos comentários.

Comment: Não querendo ser antipático, mas porque essa publicação está fora de escopo? Já vi várias publicações com conceitos extremamente simples sendo respondidas (e não fechadas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com **[c](/questions/tagged/c)** exatamente creio que não seja possível, cada ambiente gráfico tem sua própria implementação, algo que não teria dentro da linguagem, a não ser que use uma API de terceiros.

Mas não acho que necessite ir tão longe você poderia obter as variáveis de ambiente, no caso `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`, no entanto conforme esta resposta https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116694/182604 dependendo da distro ou ambientes esta variavel pode não estar disponível, então o autor sugeriu usar com *fallback* o `XDG_DATA_DIRS`

Você pode combinar com `getenv()`

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char* desk = getenv("XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP");

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Isso é apenas hipotético, você pode fazer o parte como quiser, eu não tive oportunidade de testar no CentOS ainda, mas assim que testado irei retornar o valores.

Ainda sim eu gostaria de sugerir uma coisa, não vejo porque se preocupar com o ambiente gráfico que o usuário usa, em ambientes linux para desktop eu acho o ideal que janelas de seus programas estilizem com o mesmo estilo do GUI do usuário, ao invés de ter que ficar ajustando um a um, é criar o básico e "herdar" as medidas, elementos e recursos (icones por exemplo) próprios do sistema, pois o usuário já esta familiarizado com o tal visual, isso supondo que o interesse seja ajustar algo no GUI

Agora se sua intenção é usar algum programa que vem com o gnome, você poderia simplesmente tentar executar o `exec()` ou `fork()` (depende da necessidade) e se falhar você informaria ao usuário que falta algo.

Comment: Muito obrigado, amigo! Me ajudou bastante! :)